# jQuery Ajax call with escaped characters in Uri

Tags: jquery, ajax, encodeuricomponent

I am making an Ajax call via jQuery to a `GET` service method. The problem is that the values for the parameter used can include the `/` character, so I decided to escape the special characters from the parameter by using the **`encodeURIComponent()`** method. The result is that the `/` character is transformed to `%5` and the escaped parameter is attempted to be used in an Ajax request. My code looks something like:

```
var id = "some/id";

$.ajax({
url: "http://www.mywebsite.com/getValue/" + encodeURIComponent(id),
dataType: "text",
type: 'GET',
async: true,
cache: false,

    success: function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    alert("success");       
    },

    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert("error");
    }
});
```

Somehow jQuery `unescapes` the uri value, the call to the server is not made, and I receive a Error code `404 error` (the call works fine if no `/` is present in the parameter.

Any idea how I could send such parameters on an Ajax call, or what I am doing wrong with my code?

Answer (score -1):

To avoid encoding the "/", you can replace encodeURIComponent with encodeURI. [Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aeh9cef7%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Side note - %5 is the encoded version of the backslash, whereas the example you give is for a forward slash. This may point to another additional issue.